# How to perform validation "If Priority is selected as Critical or High OR Requested Due Date is less than 10 working days show a message "

Tags: validation

How to perform validation "If Priority is selected as Critical or High OR Requested Due Date is less than 10 working days show a message. Requested due date is populated by adding 10 business days to case creation date. Is it possible to perform this validation with out using Tiggers, VF, APEX class?

Comment: This can be done with workflow. However, depending on your requirements, you may want it to be a time-dependent workflow. One question I have is, if the priority is not critical or high, do you want the workflow to fire at the due-date minus 10 day mark? Or, do you only want the workflow to fire at the time the record is edited (assuming it meets your criteria? If it's the former, you'll need to use time dependent workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just create a validation rule.
If you wish to auto set a value use formula is default values. But if default value needs reference frm other objects (cross object formula) ull HV to use trigger.

Comment: Mann -- best practice on SFSE would be to answer the question a bit more completely such as by defining the actual Validation Rule. That said, OP should have been prompted to try something first before stepping in to do his/her work

Comment: Thanks crop. Will keep that in mind. Am new to the forum. Apologies..